# Writing a CSV file to Redshift using Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, amazon-redshift

When i was trying to execute the below script i am receiving an error "too many arguments", my csv file had around 28 columns and 30 rows. All connections are working fine its reading correctly and no other issues, as per the log i understand that i cant write more than 2 or 3 columns to the table in redshift

```
import psycopg2
import csv
import time
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import sys
reload (sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')
psycopg2.extensions.register_type(psycopg2.extensions.UNICODE)
psycopg2.extensions.register_type(psycopg2.extensions.UNICODEARRAY)
print('script sterts')
connect=psycopg2.connect(dbname='db',host='***********',port=5439,user='****',password='********')
cur=connect.cursor()
print('begin execute')
up_pgm_list = pd.read_csv ('/prod/user/home/dqe933/FNI.csv')
with open('/prod/user/home/dqe933/FNI.csv', 'Ur') as csvfile:
         spamreader=csv.reader(csvfile,delimiter=',') 
         for row in spamreader:
                 cur.execute("""INSERT INTO UD_INTERIM.dqe933_fni_new(col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7,col8,col9,col10,col11,
          col12,col13,col14,col15,col16,col17,col18,col19,col20,col21,col22,col23,col24,col25,col26,col27,col28)values(?,?,?,
          ?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)""",*row)

print('complete')`enter code here`
```

Comment: Does the csv file have a header? If so you need to skip it. Also look at cur.executemany()

Answer (score 0):

`row` shouldn't be unpacked. Make sure it's an iterable consisting of **28** items.

```
cur.execute("""INSERT INTO UD_INTERIM.dqe933_fni_new(col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7,col8,col9,col10,col11,col12,col13,col14,col15,col16,col17,col18,col19,col20,col21,col22,col23,col24,col25,col26,col27,col28) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)""", row)
```

Comment: Its giving me another error.. any idea ??values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)""",row)
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near ","
LINE 3:           values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?...

Comment: Check the break in the query